# How to use multiple types with required props on the same declaration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to use this type:

```
type DataTypes =
  | Link
  | Event
  | People
  | Article
  | Department
  | PageSearch
  | OfficeSearch
  | CatalogSearch
  | DocumentSearch
  | KnowledgeSearch;
```

If I do it like this, it works properly:

```
const showOnTypeInQuery = (
    onType: string,
    cardType: (dataType: any[]) => ReactElement,
    dataType: DataTypes[]
  ): ReactElement | null => {
    if (typeInQuery === 'all' || typeInQuery === onType) {
      return cardType(dataType as DataTypes[]);
    }

    return null;
};


const getPeopleCards = (people: People[]): ReactElement => {
    return (
      <ComponentToShow
        data={people}
        heading="People"
      >
        {people.map((p: People) => (
            <PeopleCard
              people={p}
              isFetching={isFetchingData}
            />
        ))}
      </ComponentToShow>
    );
};

return showOnTypeInQuery('people', getPeopleCards, people);
```

On the function `showOnTypeInQuery` I have this param:

`cardType: (dataType: any[]) => ReactElement`

If I change to this `cardType: (dataType: DataTypes[]) => ReactElement,` it stops working and throws the following error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/searchResult/searchResults.tsx:491:38
    TS2345: Argument of type '(people: People[]) => React.ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => React.ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => React.Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => React.Component<...>)>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(dataType: DataTypes[]) => ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>'.
  Types of parameters 'people' and 'dataType' are incompatible.
    Type 'DataTypes[]' is not assignable to type 'PeopleModel[]'.
      Type 'DataTypes' is not assignable to type 'PeopleModel'.
        Property 'loginId' is missing in type 'Article' but required in type 'PeopleModel'.
```

In the `DataTypes` type I have all of those types in the same declaration because I need them in the function `showOnTypeInQuery` as parameters that will be used at some point. Those types in the `DataTypes` type contain required props but I thought that separating the types with pipelines, will make the trick.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a function whose type is `People[] => ReactElement` to a position which expects `DataTypes[] => ReactElement`, because your function might receive, for example, a `Link` type parameter and it doesn't know how to handle it, since it can only handle the `People` type.

---

I'm not very sure what you want to achieve here, but if you want to reuse showOnTypeInQuery for multiple types like `Link, Event, People` in your example, one solution is using generic like

```
const showOnTypeInQuery = <T extends DataTypes>(
    onType: string,
    cardType: (dataType: T[]) => ReactElement,
    dataType: T[]
  ): ReactElement | null => {
    if (typeInQuery === 'all' || typeInQuery === onType) {
      return cardType(dataType);
    }

    return null;
};

showOnTypeInQuery('people', getPeopleCards, people);
```